# How to use group by on multiple columns with Max function

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Here is a sample table, in which I am going to extract the records with the highest priority, corresponding to each pair of ID and code, as below:

Here is my approach to hit the mark:

```
var max = from item in items
          group item by new {item.code, item.id} into r
          select new MyObjectType(r.Select(q => q.code),
                                  r.Select(q => q.id),
                                  r.Max(q => q.priority));
```

But the result is null...

Any idea to fix the problem?!

Edit:

Here is a brief example:

```
(code,id,priority)

(1,10,100)
(1,10,200)
(1,11,300)
(1,11,400)
(2,12,500)
(2,12,600)
(2,13,700)
(2,13,800)
```

And the result of the query should be:

```
(1,10,200)
(1,11,400)
(2,12,600)
(2,13,800)
```

Comment: Can you show what's the data means items collection

Comment: @main king check my post it will help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make public properties in class and do like this:

```
var max = from item in items 
          group item by new {item.code, item.id} into r
          select new MyObjectType
                 {
                   Code = r.Key.code, 
                   Id = r.Key.id, 
                   MaxValue = r.Max(q => q.priority)
                 };
```

Your class should look like:

```
public class MyObjectType
{
   public int Code { get; set; }
   public int Id { get ; set; }
   public int MaxValue { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: That's the care, thank you... You mean the only reason for the null output was lack of filling the references to the object fields of the class?!...

Comment: You were passing them in constructor  and you didn't show class implementation  that how are you doing but normally this way is used